# How to get the request body bytes in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

The request's `content-type` is `application/json`, but I want to get the request body bytes.  Flask will auto convert the data to `json`.  How do I get the request body?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the non-form-related data by calling [`request.get_data()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/latest/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.get_data)  You can get the parsed form data by accessing [`request.form`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/latest/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.form) and `request.files`.

However, the order in which you access these two will change what is returned from `get_data`.  If you call it first, it will contain the full request body, including the raw form data.  If you call it second, it will typically be empty, and `form` will be populated.  If you want consistent behavior, call `request.get_data(parse_form_data=True)`.

You can get the body parsed as JSON by using `request.get_json()`, but this does not happen automatically like your question suggests.

See the docs on [dealing with request data](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/latest/request_data/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data as a string instead of bytes, use [`request.get_data(as_text=True)`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.get_data). This will only work if the body is actually text, not binary, data.

Answer (score 1):

To stream the data rather than reading it all at once, access [`request.stream`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.stream).

Answer (score 1):

Files in a FormData request can be accessed at `request.files` then you can select the file you included in the FormData e.g. `request.files['audio']`.

So now if you want to access the actual bytes of the file, in our case 'audio' using `.stream`, you should make sure first that your cursor points to the first byte and not to the end of the file, in which case you will get empty bytes.

Hence, a good way to do it:

```
file = request.files['audio']
file.stream.seek(0)
audio = file.read()
```

Answer (score -1):

If the data is JSON, use [`request.get_json()`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.json.JSONMixin.get_json) to parse it.