# Flask request.form is empty while request.get_data() is not

Tags: python, flask

I'm submitting form encoded data to a Flask route. If I look at the data directly with `request.get_data()`, it has the raw form encoded data. However, `request.form` is always empty, [regardless of if I call `get_data()` or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711930/how-to-get-the-request-body-bytes-in-flask). Why isn't the data parsed into `request.form`?

```
print(request.get_data())
b'reg_no=00PAS013&D2LL=True&DOCCOM_=chiave+%2B+CDC+nell%27armadio+5+25%2F06%2F2019&user_key_urlsafe=agtiY2Etb3BzLXVhdHIxCxIDQkNBIgNvcHMMCxIHQ29tcGFueRiAgICAgICACgwLEgRVc2VyGICAgICA5JEKDA&password=DUMMY%E2%82%ACuro&task_submitted_datetime=2020-01-31T17%3A31%3A43.573414'
```

```
print(request.form.to_dict())
{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue: you have to always set appropriate headers if you want any of `request.form` or `request.json` populated.

To me setting the header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` did `request.form` to work.

Set `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` to get `request.json` populated.