# Flask Stripe integration - JSON object must be str not bytes

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, stripe-payments

My virtualenv is 3.5.2 & the docs state at least 3.6 but the entire site is built in 3.5.2 so I'm hoping someone may know of a workaround...

I'm following the [docs here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder) & keep getting an error on the return `{"error": "the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'"}`

The create-payment-intent function

```
@app.route('/create-payment-intent', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_payment():
#data = json.loads(request.data) #update1
data = json.loads(request.get_data(as_text=True)) #update2
print('data is ',data,'',type(data))
try:
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
        amount=calculate_order_amount(data['items']),
        currency='usd'
    )
    return jsonify({
      'clientSecret': intent['client_secret']
    })
except Exception as e:
    return jsonify(error=str(e)), 403
```

When I open the page the error message is returned with no errors in the front end/console

[image]

Is there a simple workaround for this? I tried converting data to a string `data = str(json.loads(request.data))` but no success...

Image below added for update1

[image]

Image below added for update2

[image]

Comment: That error statement makes me think this is not a problem with `stripe` and more a problem with how your input data is structured. What does the `data` look like that's inside of the data variable? Meaning put a breakpoint on `intent = ....` and look at `data` there.

Comment: I agree with @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim.  I think it might be this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36712116/379538

Comment: Thanks for reply @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim. Please see my update1 above, I had to move it outside the try b/c I wasn't seeing anything; I guess it was just going straight to the except? Even then it still gives me more or less the same error message

Comment: Thanks for reply @floatingLomas. Please see update2 above, I also tried the `request.get_json()` too but it kept telling me `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'NoneType'`; I guess it sees None/nothing???

Comment: For any who may come across this I ended up installing py3.6 (alongside 3.5.2), created a py3.6.12 venv & now it works fine. Although I haven't tested the rest of the code base in the py3.6.12 venv yet....